# Mysql Using CSV Files Stored In Blob Field With Load Data Infile

Tags: mysql, csv, blob, load-data-infile

I am working with a database that has a series of csv files stored in blob fields.

I'd like to select the correct file (.csv) using a select with where clause, then insert records for each line in the .csv by splitting each comma separated column.

Normally, if the file were located on disk I'd use:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file-path'
INTO TABLE some-table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

or if inserting records from a select I'd use:

```
INSERT INTO target-table
SELECT * FROM source-table
WHERE condition;
```

I've also tried to pass as a variable the result of the select on the table containing the files to LOAD DATA INFILE as the file path without success.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your replies user1191247. I will try that approach and report back.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question to the one highlighted. I had read that question earlier. My question relates to selecting a blob, then parsing it's contents, then inserting each line of the file into a table (ideally in a single operation). The other question simply relates to inserting blob data using 'load data infile'.  Both questions share some keywords but clearly not related. How does being over zealous on repetition help anyone?

Comment: Thank you user1191247. Yes your approach worked well. The only improvement I made is by writing the dump file to a temp directory using the appropriate environment variable so that the dump files (which are only required for this process) are removed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load data *directly* from a CSV file stored in a blob.

A quote [from the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#:%7E:text=The%20LOAD%20DATA%20statement%20reads%20rows%20from%20a%20text%20file%20into%20a%20table%20at%20a%20very%20high%20speed.):

> The LOAD DATA statement reads rows `from a text file` into a table at a very high speed.

Assuming a table `my_blobs` like:

| id | blob_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "col head 1","col head 2","col head 3" "row1 col1","row1 col2","row 1 col3" "row 2 col1","row 2 col2","row 2 col3" ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |

A simple approach is to export all the CSV data from the table into a single file and then import it. This only works if the structure of the files in the blobs is the same and there are no (possibly limited) encoding differences.

```sql
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM blob_data) FROM my_blobs
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
FIELDS ESCAPED BY '';

LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
INTO TABLE `some-table`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

If the data in your blobs has header rows, then the headers will get imported multiple times, but they can be removed after the import.

A more convoluted (but flexible) approach is to dump the contents of the column using [`SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html) and then read the file back in to the target table using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html). This is more flexible as you can make changes to the `LOAD DATA INFILE` based on meta data in the `my_blobs` table.

You could use a query like this to write the dump/load script:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    'SELECT blob_data FROM my_blobs WHERE id = ', id,' INTO DUMPFILE \'/path/to/csv_export_', id,'.csv\';\n',
    'LOAD DATA INFILE \'/path/to/csv_export_', id,'.csv\'\nINTO TABLE `some-table`\nFIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' ENCLOSED BY \'"\'\nLINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'\nIGNORE 1 ROWS;\n\n'
) FROM my_blobs
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/process_csv_files.sql'
FIELDS ESCAPED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '';
```

Which will create the file `/path/to/process_csv_files.sql` with content like:

```sql
SELECT blob_data FROM my_blobs WHERE id = 1 INTO DUMPFILE '/path/to/csv_export_1.csv';
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/csv_export_1.csv'
INTO TABLE `some-table`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;


SELECT blob_data FROM my_blobs WHERE id = 2 INTO DUMPFILE '/path/to/csv_export_2.csv';
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/csv_export_2.csv'
INTO TABLE `some-table`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;


SELECT blob_data FROM my_blobs WHERE id = 3 INTO DUMPFILE '/path/to/csv_export_3.csv';
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/csv_export_3.csv'
INTO TABLE `some-table`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Note ([from MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html#:%7E:text=A%20given%20SELECT%20statement%20can%20contain%20at%20most%20one%20INTO%20clause%2C%20although%20as%20shown%20by%20the%20SELECT%20syntax%20description%20(see%20Section%C2%A013.2.13%2C%20%E2%80%9CSELECT%20Statement%E2%80%9D)%2C%20the%20INTO%20can%20appear%20in%20different%20positions)):

> A given `SELECT` statement can contain at most one `INTO` clause, although as shown by the `SELECT` syntax description (see [Section 13.2.13, “SELECT Statement”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)), the `INTO` can appear in different positions:
>
> - Before `FROM`. Example:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * INTO @myvar FROM t1;
>   ```
> - Before a trailing locking clause. Example:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM t1 INTO @myvar FOR UPDATE;
>   ```
> - At the end of the `SELECT`. Example:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM t1 FOR UPDATE INTO @myvar;
>   ```
>
> The `INTO` position at the end of the statement is supported as of MySQL 8.0.20, and is the preferred position. The position before a locking clause is deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.20; expect support for it to be removed in a future version of MySQL. In other words, `INTO` after `FROM` but not at the end of the `SELECT` produces a warning.

Another quote [from the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#:%7E:text=The%20file%20name%20must%20be%20given%20as%20a%20literal%20string.%20On%20Windows%2C%20specify%20backslashes%20in%20path%20names%20as%20forward%20slashes%20or%20doubled%20backslashes.):

> The file name must be given as a literal string. On Windows, specify backslashes in path names as forward slashes or doubled backslashes.

```
# Typical Windows path with secure_file_priv set
'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\file.csv'
# or
'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/file.csv'
```